# Using AND OR in MySQL not returning any results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query a table in a MySQL database.

So basically, I need to query based on the value of a column in a table. So:

if column A = value AND thisID is in an array of values

OR column A < value AND thisID is in an array of values

But the query is returning null, but the data is in the database.

EDIT: A little background on the table and what I am trying to do.

A user from the interface would select a business area. That business area could have many child areas (departments etc) and within those areas there could be many users assigned to each department. So I am passing into this query an array of users and areas.

If assigned type is 3, then the entry is assigned to a user, so I want to then check if the user(ID) is in the array so: `r.assigned_type = 3 AND r.assigned_id IN(26102,26132,26133,26134,44749)`

If assign type is 1 or 2, so less than 3, the entry is assigned to an area (site/department). so I want to check if the area(ID) is in the array, so: `r.assigned_type < 3 AND r.assigned_id IN(10901,10937,10938,10939,10940,10941)`

There could be occasions where there are entries for both users and departments which is why I need to use OR, to check for both assigned users and areas

Am i using the correct syntax? I'm not getting any syntax errors?

```
SELECT `r`.`risk_id`, `r`.`assigned_type`, `r`.`risk_type_id`, `r`.`risk_name`, `r`.`next_review`, `r`.`last_review`, `r`.`status`, `a`.`area_name`, `u`.`first_name`, `u`.`last_name`
FROM `risk_assessments` `r`
LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`id` = `r`.`assigned_id`
LEFT JOIN `areas` `a` ON `a`.`area_id` = `r`.`assigned_id`
WHERE `r`.`org_id` = 78
AND `r`.`risk_type_id` = 10
AND `r`.`assigned` = '1'
AND `u`.`privilege_level` <= 7 
AND ((`r`.`assigned_type` = '3' AND `r`.`assigned_id` IN(26102,26132,26133,26134,44749))
OR (`r`.`assigned_type` < '3' AND `r`.`assigned_id` IN(10901,10937,10938,10939,10940,10941)))
```

Comment: The logic you described does not agree with what is in the query, which, in turn may not be what you intend to do.  Off the top of my head, you could have a parentheses problem, though you should clearly tell us your logic so that someone can help you.

Comment: Can't you use IF and ELSE condition in code to check `assigned_type` and write two different queries in conditions with different JOINS?

Comment: What about CASE, can i use case on a query, depending on the value of a column

Comment: How can I use an IF statement, based on the value of a column in the same query. I don't even thinnk thats possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just make simple condition change in your query to get result as per your given example.

Here is the updated query:

```
SELECT `r`.`risk_id`, `r`.`assigned_type`, `r`.`risk_type_id`, `r`.`risk_name`, `r`.`next_review`, `r`.`last_review`, `r`.`status`, `a`.`area_name`, `u`.`first_name`, `u`.`last_name`
FROM `risk_assessments` `r`
LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`id` = `r`.`assigned_id`
LEFT JOIN `areas` `a` ON `a`.`area_id` = `r`.`assigned_id`
WHERE `r`.`org_id` = 78
AND `r`.`risk_type_id` = 10
AND `r`.`assigned` = '1'
AND `u`.`privilege_level` <= 7 
AND `r`.`assigned_type` <= '3' 
AND `r`.`assigned_id` IN(10901,10937,10938,10939,10940,10941,26102,26132,26133,26134,44749)
```

Comment: Ok, but what if there was an occasion where the user ID and the area ID are the same, that's why I need to check them independantly? I know this is probably unlikely to happen but I need to consider this

Comment: In that scenario, I believe this query will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JOIN condition:

```
LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`id` = `r`.`assigned_id`
LEFT JOIN `areas` `a` ON `a`.`area_id` = `r`.`assigned_id`
```

It seems wrong because both table joins with same `r`.`assigned_id` foreign key.

It should be like this:

```
LEFT JOIN `users` `u` ON `u`.`id` = `r`.`user_id` (foreign key for users table)
LEFT JOIN `areas` `a` ON `a`.`area_id` = `r`.`area_id` (foreign key for areas table)
```

Comment: assigned_id is the column. Whether that is a userID or an areaID is determined by the assigned type column